# Download zipped csv file after extracting it

Tags: excel, vba

I have the url which contains a zipped csv file, I need to download only .csv from the zip , the Codes below is downloading zip

```
Sub DownloadFile()

    Dim myURL As String
    myURL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2020/FEB/cm07FEB2020bhav.csv.zip"

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Users\playt\Desktop\STACK\ruff.zip", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You have to download the whole zip and then process it. There is no option to only get one file from it otherwise.

Comment: actually there is only 1 file in zip and that is .csv file,

Comment: Well then you should have no problems then, right?

Comment: yes, But I want to have only csv file in destination folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717193/unzip-file-through-excel-vba-code

Comment: Then delete any other files in the destination folder...

Comment: will definitely try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file from an archive, but you can adapt your code in the next way:

Insert this lines at the end of your existing code (just before `End Sub`):

```
Dim zipFileName As String, unZipFolderName As String
  zipFileName = "C:\Users\playt\Desktop\STACK\ruff.zip"

  unZipFolderName = left(zipFileName, InStrRev(zipFileName, "\") - 1)
  UN_Zip zipFileName, unZipFolderName
```

The simplest sub able to unzip and delete the archive must look like that (it needs a reference to `'Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation'`):

```
Private Sub UN_Zip(zipFileName As String, unZipFolderName As String)
     Dim wShApp As New Shell

     wShApp.Namespace(unZipFolderName).CopyHere wShApp.Namespace(zipFileName).Items
      Kill zipFileName
 End Sub
```

If too lazy for adding the reference, to make the code look more elegant, the sub can be adapted with only two lines:

Use `Dim wShApp As Object` instead of `Dim wShApp As New Shell` declaration and then add the next line:

```
Set ShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
```

In this way, no reference is necessary, anymore...