# Is there a Special Method for extracting PKZip files with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, unzip

I'm attempting to use a fairly standard method for pulling emails from Outlook and then extracting Zip files.  The File names and the folder locations are correct.  I wonder if PKZip files (our corporate standard for Zip files) requires a special technique?  Here's my code so far...  It works perfectly up to the point where files are extracted from the Zip files where it fails.  (oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items)

```vb
Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim fDest As String
    Dim fZip As String
               
    strDate = InputBox("Enter Date in format dd-Mmm-yyyy", "User Date", Format(Now(), "dd-Mmm-yyyy"))
       
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders("GCMNamLogs").Folders("Inbox")
    
    fDest = "C:\Users\jb76991\Desktop\0_SWPA 50011 CORP Violations\"
        
    For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict("@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strDate & "%'")
        
        If i.Class = olMail Then
            Set mi = i
            For Each at In mi.Attachments
                If InStr(at.Filename, ".zip") > 0 Then
                    If InStr(mi.Subject, "Daily SWPA swpaViolRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:CORP") > 0 Then
                        'Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        FileNameFolder = fDest
                        Fname = at.Filename
                        at.SaveAsFile fDest & Fname
                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        Debug.Print fDest & Fname
                        oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
                    End If
                    If InStr(mi.Subject, "Daily SWPA swpaViolRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:INFRA") > 0 Then
                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        FileNameFolder = fDest
                        Fname = at.Filename
                        at.SaveAsFile fDest & Fname
                        Debug.Print fDest & Fname
                        oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                    End If
                    If InStr(mi.Subject, "Daily SWPA swpaSumRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:CORP") > 0 Then
                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        FileNameFolder = fDest
                        Fname = at.Filename
                        at.SaveAsFile fDest & Fname
                        Debug.Print fDest & Fname
                        oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                    End If
                    If InStr(mi.Subject, "Daily SWPA swpaSumRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:INFRA") > 0 Then
                        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        FileNameFolder = fDest
                        Fname = at.Filename
                        at.SaveAsFile fDest & Fname
                        Debug.Print fDest & Fname
                        oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items
                        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                    End If

                End If
            Next at
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: To achieve what I think you're trying to achieve, first you need to extract the attachment (the zip file) from the Outlook message (this might be helpful for that step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531093/save-attachments-to-a-folder-and-rename-them), then you need to extract the files from zip file. This code is not doing either of those things as far as I can tell. When you say "it fails", can you be a bit more specific? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @Nicholas Thank you for taking a look.  The error is Run-Time Error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set.  The code currently pulls the email attachments and saves them to "C:\Users\jb76991\Desktop\0_SWPA 50011 CORP Violations".  If you comment out the extraction part of the code, all attachments are pulled and saved there.

Comment: OK Sorry I misspoke. I see where the attachments are saved to the network folder. But I am pretty sure that oApp.Namespace(fDest).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(fDest & Fname).Items is not going to extract files from the zip file. It looks like this command copies items from one Outlook folder to another. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere

Comment: There might be an external library you can use to extract files from a zip file. I used have to use the Shell command. It worked but it was hella clunky.

Comment: Check out my `UnZip` function found [here](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress).

Comment: @NicholasHunter I see that one of my Shell commands is commented out, but uncommenting does not fix the issue.  I've seen here and other places where files are extracted to the network:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717193/unzip-folder-with-files-to-the-chosen-location], so I don't believe that part of the code is an issue. I would definitely appreciate some insights.

Comment: @Gustav...  I can't access this link

Comment: It's a public link, so I can't tell why, sorry.

Comment: I'm stumped. Did you try putting a breakpoint on the line that's giving you the error and checking all the variables have the proper values? That's all I can suggest.

Comment: Any values passed in as parameters to Shell methods should be declared as `Variant`, not as `String`.  String values do not play well with Shell

Comment: @TimWilliams that did it!!!  Drat my stubborn self...

Answer (score 0):

The string/variant is the fix, but you'd also benefit from reducing the repetition in the code

(untested)

```vb
Sub SaveAttachments()
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim i As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim fDest As Variant, FName As Variant, e, arrZips
    
    strDate = InputBox("Enter Date in format dd-Mmm-yyyy", "User Date", Format(Now(), "dd-Mmm-yyyy"))
       
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders("GCMNamLogs").Folders("Inbox")
    
    arrZips = Array("Daily SWPA swpaViolRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:CORP", _
                    "Daily SWPA swpaViolRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:INFRA", _
                    "Daily SWPA swpaSumRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:CORP", _
                    "Daily SWPA swpaSumRPT REPORT for DOMAIN:INFRA")
    
    fDest = "C:\Users\jb76991\Desktop\0_SWPA 50011 CORP Violations\"
        
    For Each i In fol.items.Restrict("@SQL=urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strDate & "%'")
        If i.Class = olMail Then
            Set mi = i
            For Each at In mi.Attachments
                FName = at.Filename
                If InStr(FName, ".zip") > 0 Then
                    For Each e In arrZips
                        If InStr(mi.Subject, e) > 0 Then
                            at.SaveAsFile fDest & FName
                            ExtractZip fDest & FName, fDest, 2
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next e
                End If
            Next at
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox ("Done")
End Sub

Sub ExtractZip(ZipPath, DestFolder, Optional waitsecs As Long = 0)
    Debug.Print "Extracting '" & ZipPath & "' to '" & DestFolder & "'"
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        .Namespace(DestFolder).copyhere .Namespace(ZipPath).items
    End With
    If waitsecs > 0 Then Application.Wait Now + waitsecs / (24 * 60 * 60)
End Sub
```